# Linking to images in Timber / Twig using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I am new to the world of Twig and Timber, I have just started a new job and I am having difficulty getting to grips with using it.
I have been supplied a completed design in Twig which I have converted to a wordpress site and I am now trying to make it editable via ACF. In my front-page.php I have set the following:

$context['data'] = get_fields();

Then within the home page (twig file) of the supplied designs I was given, here is a section of code:

```
{% include [
    'override/pullquote.twig', 
    'components/pullquote.twig'
    ] with {
    'title': data.my_story_title,
    'section_class': 'light pullquote-standalone text-center',
    'image': data.my_story_image, 
    'blockquote': data.my_story_quote,
    'cite': '',
    'link_footer': "Read Ramon's story",
    'link_path': '#',
} %}
```

So I have created ACF options for **title** and **blockquote**, and using **data.my_story_title** and **data.my_story_quote** these work fine. However, the ***data.my_story_image*** does not, it does nothing. Where am I going wrong with this? Presumably I have to expand on it with it being and image but I'm not sure how. It is probably a simple thing - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACF normally returns an image ID therefore you likely need to convert the field value into an TimberImage before passing it to the template. Try :

```
'image': Image( data.my_story_image )
```

Also heres some useful documentation on using ACF with Timber/twig: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/

Comment: Based on this solution, which works great for pulling from ACF, how would I use it to pull from the theme folder? For example, with a normal image link this works fine:

<img src="{{theme.link}}/assets/images/phone.svg">

However, when I use it as above it doesn't work:

'image': Image ("{{theme.link}}/assets/images/phone.svg"),

I have also tried without the brackets. Do you have any idea how I'd make this work?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It doesn't work because your asset does not exist within WP as an Media Item record. I assume you have a set number of assets that you intent to use so you could hard code these into the template with a conditional statement, i.e if 'image' is "phone" use set path else use media item

Comment: Do you mind also marking my initial answer as correct?